# How to check whether a Storage item is set?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

How can I check if an item is set in `localStorage`? Currently I am using

```
if (!(localStorage.getItem("infiniteScrollEnabled") == true || localStorage.getItem("infiniteScrollEnabled") == false)) {
    // init variable/set default variable for item
    localStorage.setItem("infiniteScrollEnabled", true);
}
```

Comment: seems, you will have a problem without a storage mutex

Answer (score 691, accepted):

The [`getItem`](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#dom-storage-getitem) method in the WebStorage specification, explicitly returns [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) if the item does not exist:

> ... If the given key does not exist in the list associated with the object then this method must return null. ...

So, you can:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("infiniteScrollEnabled") === null) {
  //...
}
```

See this related question:

- [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage/)

Comment: Could you add your own method to `localStorage` to encapsulate this little test? E.g. `localStorage.hasItem("infiniteScrollEnabled")`?

Comment: @Paul: Yes, you could even augment the `Storage.prototype` object, but as a rule of thumb I always recommend to [not modify objects you don't own](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/), specially host objects.

Comment: ooh yeah, good points in there. Coming from a CSS background, the idea that I can fix browser issues myself is exciting, but I can see how mucking around with the browser’s objects could get confusing.

Comment: Thanks! However, since the question tries to set a value in Storage to true and checks if it's true, it may be a good idea to mention that keys and values can only be strings, and anything you pass as a value is implicitly converted to a string.

Answer (score 79):

You can use `hasOwnProperty` method to check this

```
> localStorage.setItem('foo', 123)
undefined
> localStorage.hasOwnProperty('foo')
true
> localStorage.hasOwnProperty('bar')
false
```

Works in current versions of Chrome(Mac), Firefox(Mac) and Safari.

Comment: It should be the accepted answer. The accepted one will consider a stored "null" value as not set, which is wrong.

Comment: @FlavienVolken You can not have a stored `null` value though. You can have `"null"`, but the code there will not misbehave on it, while this one will fail on `length` key.

Comment: @Kaiido you are right, I had this behaviour because I was directly parsing the stored data and as `JSON.parse("null") === JSON.parse(null)` I had a collision.

Comment: Got the following ESLint error: "Do not access Object.prototype method 'hasOwnProperty' from target object.eslint(no-prototype-builtins)"

Comment: This won't work if foo is not set on page load and you want to do something with foo. I think that is what the questioner was getting at, you want to check if the key `foo` exists, not if foo has a value. I have this situation, where a click event triggers `.setitem` with logic based around getItem,but it won't work until I setItem, and I can't setItem until I know foo's state (value1 or value2). In other words, check foo exits then set it to value1 if it does not without accidentally overwriting value2.

Answer (score 24):

The shortest way is to use default value, if key is not in storage:

```
var sValue = localStorage['my.token'] || ''; /* for strings */
var iValue = localStorage['my.token'] || 0; /* for integers */
```

Answer (score 8):

```
if(!localStorage.hash) localStorage.hash = "thinkdj";
```

Or

```
var secret =  localStorage.hash || 42;
```

---

Updated:

```
let scrollEnabled = localStorage?.scrollEnabled??true;
```

Comment: JavaScript returns the first non-null or positive value 

Examples:

[ null || "abc" ] will return "abc"
[ 2 || 5 ] will return 2
[ 0 || 5 ] will return 5
[ 1 || 5 ] will return 1
etc. Hence the above code works.

Answer (score 8):

there are couple of methods to check i am adding them here

Method 1

```
if("infiniteScrollEnabled" in localStorage){
     console.log("Item exists in localstorage");
}else{
    console.log("Item does not exist in localstoarge";
}
```

Method 2

```
if(localStorage.getItem("infiniteScrollEnabled") === null){
    console.log("Item does not exist in localstoarge";
}else{
   console.log("Item exists in localstorage");
}
```

Method 3

```
if(typeof localStorage["cart"] === "undefined"){
    console.log("Item does not exist in localstoarge";
}else{
   console.log("Item exists in localstorage");
}
```

Method 4

```
if(localStorage.hasOwnProperty("infiniteScrollEnabled")){
     console.log("Item exists in localstorage");
 }else{
    console.log("Item does not exist in localstoarge";
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Can try something like this:

```
 let x = localStorage.getItem('infiniteScrollEnabled') === null ? "not found" : localStorage.getItem('infiniteScrollEnabled')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also try this if you want to check for undefined:

```
if (localStorage.user === undefined) {
    localStorage.user = "username";
}
```

getItem is a method which returns null if value is not found.

Answer (score 3):

For TRUE

```
localStorage.infiniteScrollEnabled = 1;
```

FOR FALSE

```
localStorage.removeItem("infiniteScrollEnabled")
```

CHECK EXISTANCE

```
if (localStorage[""infiniteScrollEnabled""]) {
  //CODE IF ENABLED
}
```

Comment: good one, worked in my case

Answer (score 3):

How can one test existence of an item in `localStorage`?
this method works in internet explorer.

```
<script>
    try{
        localStorage.getItem("username");
    }catch(e){
        alert("we are in catch "+e.print);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It certainly shouldn't; getItem just returns null for keys that don't exist.

Comment: I was having the same issue with IE, and this is the fix for it, ++

Comment: You should definitely `try | catch` when parsing the item.

Answer (score 2):

Best and Safest way i can suggest is this,

```
if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(localStorage, 'infiniteScrollEnabled')){
    // init variable/set default variable for item
    localStorage.setItem("infiniteScrollEnabled", true);
}
```

This passes through ESLint's [`no-prototype-builtins`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-prototype-builtins) rule.

Answer (score 1):

You should check for the **type** of the item in the localStorage

```
if(localStorage.token !== null) {
   // this will only work if the token is set in the localStorage
}

if(typeof localStorage.token !== 'undefined') {
  // do something with token
}

if(typeof localStorage.token === 'undefined') {
  // token doesn't exist in the localStorage, maybe set it?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used in my project and works perfectly for me

```
var returnObjName= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ObjName'));
if(returnObjName && Object.keys(returnObjName).length > 0){
   //Exist data in local storage
}else{
  //Non Exist data block
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to this party, but checking localStorage for the existence of keys (or the existence of key values) is easily done with [**localDataStorage**](https://github.com/macmcmeans/localDataStorage), a handy utility wrapper I created.

After instantiating the wrapper with something like

```
myLDS = localDataStorage( 'segmentedStorageHere' );
```

you can set keys

```
myLDS.set( 'infiniteScrollEnabled', true );
```

in a straightforward manner. Note that this example is actually passing a *boolean* value to the store, where it can be retrieved with

```
let scrollingState = myLDS.get( 'infiniteScrollEnabled' );
```

and *scrollingState* will contain the boolean value returned. The wrapper keeps track of the native JavaScript data type for you, seamlessly (Array, Boolean, Date, Number, Object, etc.) No more JSON stringifying/parsing in your code.

Now when we need to know if a key is in the store, we can check it like this

```
if( myLDS.haskey( 'infiniteScrollEnabled' ) ) {
    console.log( "It's been set!" ); 
} else {
    console.log( "The key is not set." ); 
}
```

You can also check whether a particular value is present. For example

```
myLDS.set( 'myNumber', 1234.5678 );
console.log( myLDS.hasval( 1234.5678 ) );    --> true
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Christian C. Salvadó has mentioned above you can do
`if (xxx === null){}`

but null is also a falsy value, like so:

```
if (null){
console.log ("hello");
}
```

which does not print "hello".

Answer (score 0):

```
localStorage['root2']=null;

localStorage.getItem("root2") === null //false
```

Maybe better to do a scan of the plan  ?

```
localStorage['root1']=187;
187
'root1' in localStorage
true
```

Answer (score 0):

I always check if **localStorage** or **sessionStorage** is set by checking the length of them

```
if (sessionStorage.length > 0) {
  console.log("exists")
} else {
  console.log("not exists")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
if (localStorage.getItem("infiniteScrollEnabled") === null) {
```

is not working for me. Perhaps it's because things have changed since this answer was provided. Today, in 2023, the following command works for me:

```
if (!localStorage.getItem("infiniteScrollEnabled")) {
```

Note that this is actually the method recommended in the MDN web docs at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API#testing_whether_your_storage_has_been_populated.

Answer (score -3):

Try this code

```
if (localStorage.getItem("infiniteScrollEnabled") === null) {

} else {

}
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.