# `prop in localStorage` vs `localStorage.getItem('prop')!==null`

Tags: javascript, html, object, local-storage, javascript-objects

The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262605/html5-localstorage-check-if-item-is-set) question recommends:

```
localStorage.getItem('prop') !== null
```

However, I want to keep my code consistent and I want to use:

```
'prop' in localStorage
```

Is there anything wrong with the second form? In terms of speed, it should be insignificantly faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This difference is that [the `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) will walk the prototype chain, but `getItem` will only return data set on the object itself.

So something like this will always return `true`, even though you never set an item by that key:

```
'toString' in localStorage
```

This probably is not the intended behavior, so you will probably want to avoid it in this case.

One way you could have more-consistent code would be to use [the `hasOwnProperty` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty). This method is available on all objects, including `localStorage`. Keep in mind that is does behave differently from both `getItem` and `in`, as it returns boolean and will not walk the prototype chain.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `getItem(prop) !== null` test because `in` cannot distinguish between the values stored in `localStorage` from the non-enumerable properties of that object (or those inherited from its prototype chain).

A good example is that `'getItem' in localStorage === true`