# Ionic Pop up alert for first time only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework

I have a pop up tutorial (basically slider) that will show upon first launch in the app. This is what I wrote in the controller.js

```
  //show first time tutorial
  if(localStorage.getItem("second") != "true")
  {
  $ionicPopup.show({
  template: '<ion-slide-box class="first_tutorial">\
      <ion-slide>\
        <img class="img1" />\
      </ion-slide>\
      <ion-slide>\
        <img class="img2" />\
      </ion-slide>\
      <ion-slide>\
        <img class="img3" />\
      </ion-slide>\
      <ion-slide>\
        <img class="img4" />\
      </ion-slide>\
    </ion-slide-box>',
  scope: $scope,
  cssClass: 'tutorial_popup_dlg',
  buttons: [
    { text: 'Got It' }
  ]
});
localStorage.setItem("second", "true");
  }
  //--show first time tutorial
```

But it is not working...any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you are checking condition in if statement then you don't have item `second` in localStorage

Write your if condition as follow

```
if(localStorage.getItem("second")==undefined)
```

Comment: Change your if condition as mention in answer.

Comment: unfortunately it is not working =(

What could possibly lead it to not working, if it used to work ?

Comment: Try to alert localStorage.getItem("second")

Comment: sorry, where should i add it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the localstorage item exist.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262605/html5-localstorage-check-if-item-is-set) for further explanation.

```
if (localStorage.getItem("second") === null) {
  //...
}
```