# Ionic/Angular: Read and Write Array in Local Storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ionic-framework, local-storage

I'm working with Ionic framework as part of an online course I'm taking to learn AngularJS and a great many other tools useful to a web developer. And, being the sort of advanced beginner type, I'm stuck. In this unit, we've learned to leverage local storage to persist data locally so we can get our favourite items even after the app is shut down. However, I have trouble getting that to work.

So here's what I've done:

### The Failed Attempt

I can get data into local storage. And I can append data. I do this using this function:

```
$scope.favoriteData = $localStorage.getObject('favorites', '[]');

$scope.addFavorite = function (index) {
    console.log('Current Favorites', $scope.favoriteData);
    $scope.favoriteData =  Object.keys($scope.favoriteData).map(function(k) { return $scope.favoriteData[k] });
    console.log ($scope.favoriteData);
    $scope.storeVar = $scope.favoriteData.push("'{id':" + index + '},');
    console.log ($scope.favoriteData);
    $localStorage.storeObject('favorites', $scope.favoriteData);
    console.log('Added Favorite', $scope.favoriteData)
};
```

In local storage, this produces the following entry:

```
favorites: ["'{id':0},","'{id':1},"]
```

So far so good. However, this is useless. Because I need this object to have the following format:

```
favorites: [{'id':0}, {'id':1}]
```

and so on. Also, I should not be able to add duplicates. I have a kind of function for that elsewhere, but I am stuck on how to combine the two functions.

The function I have is this:

```
function (index) {
        for (var i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++) {
            if (favorites[i].id == index)
                return;
        }
        favorites.push({
            id: index
        });
    };
```

The problem with this is, I don't understand how it does what it does.

So please, help?

EDIT #1:

### The Second Attempt

With the help of @Muli and @It-Z I'm working with the following code right now:

```
$scope.favoriteData = $localStorage.getObject('favorites', '[]');

$scope.addFavorite = function (index) {
    console.log('Current Favorites', $scope.favoriteData);
    $scope.favoriteData =  Object.keys($scope.favoriteData).map(function(k) { return $scope.favoriteData[k] });
    console.log ($scope.favoriteData);
    for (var i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++) {
        if (favorites[i].id == index) {
            console.log ("Found duplicate id " + favorites[i].id);
            return;
        }
    }
    $scope.storeVar = $scope.favoriteData.push({id: index});
    console.log ($scope.favoriteData);
    $localStorage.storeObject('favorites', $scope.favoriteData);
    console.log('Added Favorite', $scope.favoriteData)
};
```

However, this doesn't work because with a nonexistant key `favorites`, it doesn't work and gives me an error. So I need to implement a check if the key exists and if it doesn't, then it should create one. I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262605/html5-localstorage-check-if-item-is-set) question, but it didn't work, mainly because I must use the following factory in `services.js`to access local storage:

```
.factory('$localStorage', ['$window', function ($window) {
    return {
        store: function (key, value) {
            $window.localStorage[key] = value;
        },
        get: function (key, defaultValue) {
            return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
        },
        storeObject: function (key, value) {
            $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
        },
        getObject: function (key, defaultValue) {
            return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue);
        }
    }
}])
```

So this is where I'm at right now. And I'm still stuck. Or again stuck. I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this line:

```
$scope.storeVar = $scope.favoriteData.push("'{id':" + index + '},');
```

Should be:

```
$scope.storeVar = $scope.favoriteData.push({id: index});
```

This is because in the original line you are pushing string into `favoriteData` while you wanted objects.

And if you want to check first for duplicates your can go with somthing like this:

```
$scope.favoriteData = $localStorage.getObject('favorites', []);

$scope.addFavorite = function (index) {
    console.log('Current Favorites', $scope.favoriteData);
    $scope.favoriteData =  Object.keys($scope.favoriteData).map(function(k) { return $scope.favoriteData[k] });
    console.log ($scope.favoriteData);
    for (var i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++) {
        if (favorites[i].id == index) {
            console.log ("Found duplicate id " + favorites[i].id);
            return;
        }
    }
    $scope.storeVar = $scope.favoriteData.push({id: index});
    console.log ($scope.favoriteData);
    $localStorage.storeObject('favorites', $scope.favoriteData);
    console.log('Added Favorite', $scope.favoriteData)
};
```

Comment: Using this, after having cleared my local storage, I get a weird error going "favorites is not defined". So I guess I would need to create an empty local storage entry first?

Comment: Yes, if favorites dose not exist (you should add a check for it) you need to create it first.

Comment: Sorry for sounding so thick, but I'm new at this. I just checked the rest of StackOverflow for a solution and I can't get this to work. At all. I get an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier.

Comment: Where? You can try $scope.favoriteData = $localStorage.favoriteData || {/*Defaults object*/}; as @muli yulzari suggests

Comment: I've tested [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262605/html5-localstorage-check-if-item-is-set) one and it didn't work. Maybe because I don't have setItem available and - due to course limitations - I can't have it available.

Comment: You are mixing two different things... Have you learned about 'if' or 'try' block? What is your current code? What have you tried? Where exactly is it failing again?

Comment: I know of `if` but I've never worked with `try`. I've updated the original posting to add the code I'm currently working with. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Found it. Try this first line $scope.favoriteData = $localStorage.getObject('favorites', []); I have removed the string and returning array as default.

Comment: @Zeke - please let me know if this works for you or if you need any further assistance.

Answer (score 2):

$localStorage handles serialization and deserialization for you so there's no need for `$scope.favoriteData = $localStorage.getObject('favorites', '[]');`

You can just call:

```
$scope.favoriteData = $localStorage.favoriteData || {/*Defaults object*/};
```

Same goes for saving data. use the **dot** notation.

Check the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3vfRkvG7R9DgQxtWbGHz?p=preview).

As for the duplicates: just handle them yourself like you would normally. when you're done call `$localStorage.mySet = modifiedSet` (modified set is standard JS object).

Note: this assumes you use ngStorage.

Comment: I use this factory to do this, I think:

.factory('$localStorage', ['$window', function ($window) {
    return {
        store: function (key, value) {
            $window.localStorage[key] = value;
        },
        get: function (key, defaultValue) {
            return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
        },
        storeObject: function (key, value) {
            $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
        },
        getObject: function (key, defaultValue) {
            return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue);
        }
    }
}])

Comment: This is unreadable. Just use the one I gave you. It's already written the angular way.

Comment: Sorry about the inconvenience with the code. It looked alright when I pasted it. And I don't think I can use your method, I'm afraid as it would be against the course specs. I mean, I appreciate your work, don't get me wrong, it's just that the person grading it will probably give me a fail if I don't work with what we've dealt with during the course. :(

Comment: Aha I didn't know it was that kind of course. I'll update my answer if I'll get my hands off work.