# Want to set show/hide script visible by default

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to set a show/hide js script that is using localstorage on by default.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var sidebarVisible = localStorage.getItem('sidebar') == 'true';
  $('#sidebar').toggle(sidebarVisible);
  $('.bgcontainer_center').toggleClass('clicked', sidebarVisible);

  $("#toggle").click(function () {
    $("#sidebar").toggle("slow", function () {
      localStorage.setItem('sidebar', $('#sidebar').is(':visible'));
    });

    $(".bgcontainer_center").toggleClass('clicked');
  });
});
```

This is the link to it https://jsfiddle.net/eo12xw79/67/

I can't seem to find how to set it on by default.

Comment: Do you want the main content to be the default one?

Comment: It is working fine in my case....'

Comment: Could just check for not false and leave the rest as it is, since all that is not false is true in your case (first time && visible). Also be aware that not all settings and browsers allow access to localStorange, in which case the check on not false is also better.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it isn't toggled is because the `sidebar` key isn't present in the browser's `localstorage` the first time we visit the page.

There is a very simple solution, just have to check if the `sidebar` key exists in the `localstorage` and if not, create it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // BEGIN
    if(!localStorage.getItem('sidebar')) {
        localStorage.setItem('sidebar', 'true');
    }
    // END

    var sidebarVisible = localStorage.getItem('sidebar') == 'true';
    $('#sidebar').toggle(sidebarVisible);
    $('.bgcontainer_center').toggleClass('clicked', sidebarVisible);

    $("#toggle").click(function () {
        $("#sidebar").toggle("slow", function () {
            localStorage.setItem('sidebar', $('#sidebar').is(':visible'));
        });

        $(".bgcontainer_center").toggleClass('clicked');
    });
});
```

**EDIT :** I think it's useless, why ?
Because you will use the `localstorage` for a single variable that has no real importance.
After, this is only a personal opinion, it depends on your needs.

**DUPLICATE :** [How to check whether a Storage item is set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262605/how-to-check-whether-a-storage-item-is-set)

Comment: Delighted to have been able to help you. You can check the checkmark to inform the community that your question has been resolved.

Comment: localStorage.getItem('sidebar') == null instead just write !localStorage.getItem('sidebar')

Comment: @eugene_sunic yes it's true, i've edited my post thank you ! :D