# set local storage on submit and and get it if page is refreshed

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage

I am trying to set form data in local storage after submitting the form. If the page is refreshed I have to print in the console that "form submitted already". I don't know how to write reload condition My code is below

```
submit(){
localStorage.setItem('form-data', JSON.stringify(this.shippingForm.value));
}
window.reload(){
    let formValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('form-data'));
    console.log("form submitted alreay");
}
```

Comment: You want to just check whether the local storage is set no `submit()` or need to check whenever the page loads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to do use `getItem`. It will return null if the item doesn't exist

```
if (localStorage.getItem("form-data") === null) {
  // do nothing
} else {
    console.log("form submitted alreay");
}
```

Here is the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3262605/3282633) your can read more about it.

In your case the you can have something like this

```
window.reload(){
if (localStorage.getItem("form-data") === null) {
      // do nothing
    } else {
        // do your other conversions here
        console.log("form submitted alreay");
    }
}
```

**Note :** Do not forget to clear the `localstorage` whenever you're done

Comment: in my case window.reload() also throwing error.  Can you pls tell me whrer to write page refresh function?

Comment: You can do that in document ready also .. Do you have jquery loaded in your page ?