# How can I store value to the browser localStorage for the first time?

Tags: javascript

Here I declared a variable with value from local storage `var yourLink = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('linkID'));` but the problem is when there is no value for the first time this is not working. So, I tried to add another `if` statement where there is no value found then assign a value to the `yourLink` variable. But couldn't do it. What can I try next?

Here I give the full code:

```
var link = ["https://www.facebook.com/", "https://stackoverflow.com/"];


var yourLink = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('linkID'));



localStorage.setItem('linkID', yourLink);


if ((parseInt(localStorage.getItem('linkID')))<= 7 ) {
    yourLink = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('linkID')) + 1;
    localStorage.setItem('linkID', yourLink);

    yourLink = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('linkID'))

    window.open(link[0], '_blank');


} else if ((parseInt(localStorage.getItem('linkID'))) >= 8) {
    yourLink = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('linkID')) + 1;
    localStorage.setItem('linkID', yourLink);

    yourLink = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('linkID'))

    window.open(link[1], '_blank');

    yourLink = 0;
    localStorage.setItem('linkID', yourLink);
}
```

Comment: You can check if localStorage has some value or not using if condition. Like `if(!localStorage.getItem('linkID'))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check whether a Storage item is set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262605/how-to-check-whether-a-storage-item-is-set)

Comment: Initially, I want to store `0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in your question, none of the times the data is being set in `localStorage` as `parseInt(localStorage.getItem('linkID'))` will be `NaN`. So what you can do is

```js
var link = ["https://www.facebook.com/", "https://stackoverflow.com/"];

if(!localStorage.getItem('linkID')) {
   localStorage.setItem('linkID', 0);
}

if ((parseInt(localStorage.getItem('linkID')))<= 7 ) {
    yourLink = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('linkID')) + 1;
    localStorage.setItem('linkID', yourLink);

    yourLink = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('linkID'))

    window.open(link[0], '_blank');

} else if ((parseInt(localStorage.getItem('linkID'))) >= 8) {
    yourLink = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('linkID')) + 1;
    localStorage.setItem('linkID', yourLink);

    yourLink = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('linkID'))

    window.open(link[1], '_blank');

    yourLink = 0;
    localStorage.setItem('linkID', yourLink);
}
```

Hope this helps in solving your problem.

Comment: My pleasure. I'm glad that it helped you :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this condition for determining whether it is the first time

```
if(localStorage.getItem('linkID') == null){
    // do your logic here
}
```