# How can I refer to local storage as empty?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, local-storage

I have a series of if and else if statements and what I want is to determine a scenario in terms of local storage being empty.

I've tried:

```
(if localStorage.getItem('example') == localStorage.clear()) {

//Do something if that local storage item is empty
}
```

I am aware the program may think I'm assigning the local storage to clear out it's contents. So would I do something like:

```
(if localStorage.getItem('example') == localStorage()) {

//Do something if that local storage item is empty
}
```

If not, how can I refer to the local storage as an empty object so the program doesn't get confused thinking that I'd like to clear the contents in the storage?

Comment: In the first case you’re clearing the localStorage every time. In the second localStorage is not a function so it can’t be called.

Comment: Yes, that's why I believe that's not the way to go in terms of identifying if it's empty.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check whether a Storage item is set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262605/how-to-check-whether-a-storage-item-is-set)

Answer (score 2):

You can check to see if it is null.

```
if(localStorage.getItem('example') === null){
 console.log("x");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok both answers posted are right. However, I want to explain a few things that I have experienced. Undefined is returned if you are referring to the object as so and it has nothing in it:

```
localStorage.key; //will be undefined if not set
```

localStorage.getItem() returns null if nothing is in it (as I have experienced).

```
localStorage.getItem('key'); //will return null if not set
```

And yes, all you have to do is check if it is null or undefined (depending on the method you use)

```
if(localStorage.getItem('key') === null){
   //do stuff here
}
```

or

```
if(localStorage.key === undefined){
   //do stuff here
}
```

or you can use the ! operator like so:

```
if(!localStorage.getItem('key')){
   //do stuff here
}
```

or

```
if(!localStorage.key){
   //do stuff here
}
```

The reason for this is because both null and undefined are falsely values, and the ! operator checks for falsely values

Answer (score 0):

You can just check if `localStorage.getItem()` is `undefined`. Here's an example:

```
function isCleared(item) {
  return !localStorage.getItem(item)
}
```