# Object is possibly null in Angular 11

Tags: typescript, local-storage, angular11

The following code gives the `Object is possibly null` error in line `+localStorage.getItem('PID')`:

```
newPropID() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('PID')) {
    localStorage.setItem('PID', String(+localStorage.getItem('PID') + 1));
    return +localStorage.getItem('PID');
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('PID', '101');
    return 101;
  }
}
```

I want to check if there's a record in local storage and store another record. How can I  fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check whether a Storage item is set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262605/how-to-check-whether-a-storage-item-is-set)

Comment: you should refactor - get the PID. check that is null set it to 101 else increment and return the increment. You duplicate code to increment as is. Also you assign 101 twice - what if you want a different seed (101 atm). 2 places to update. Maintainability...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript can infer the possible value if you abstract it to a variable:

```
newPropID() {
  const PID = localStorage.getItem('PID');
  if (PID) {
    const updatedPID = String(+PID + 1);

    localStorage.setItem('PID', updatedPID);
    return updatedPID;
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('PID', '101');
    return 101;
  }
}
```