# Check if there is a value in localStorage, if not display an alternate message (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm still a newbie developer and would really appreciate some help. The below function on() is called from within another function when the user scores 10/10 on a quiz.  The username is initially created from a username login on a different page and that value is successfully stored in localStorage.  That part is working fine and I can call that value (within the on() function) using the first part of the below statement if I leave out the first 'if' statement line and the entire 'else if' statement.  However, I'm trying to cater for the time should the user not enter a username, because when the first part of the on() function is called it displays the following: "Congratulations {null}! You scored the perfect 10".  I would prefer it to display the alternate message within the 'else if' section below.  Any guidance on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

```
function on() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("users") == true) {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("overlay").innerText = "Congratulations " +
    window.localStorage.getItem('users') + "! You scored the perfect 10!";
    } else 
    if (localStorage.getItem("users") === null) {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("overlay").innerText = "Congratulations! You scored the perfect 10!";
}
```

Comment: Can you share what is being stored in the localStorage?

Comment: Your indentation is confusing, but if I add the final `}` and indent properly I get code that looks more or less fine and [works as expected](https://jsfiddle.net/7qg3p0rc/). The problem I guess is that you're storing a string in localStorage, so your check should look like this: `if (localStorage.getItem("users"))` (you can omit `!== null` from the check) And you only need an `else`, you don't need to compare the entire thing against null again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262605/how-to-check-whether-a-storage-item-is-set

Comment: Sorry, how do I add further code?

Comment: @ChrisG - I added the extra bracket, but it doesn't display the alternate message.

Comment: That curly brace will make or break your syntax; please always check the browser console for errors (press F12). Did you change the test like my code suggested? I.e. use  just `if (localStorage.getItem("users"))` and `else`? Here's a rewritten version: https://jsfiddle.net/hqj5d2mL/ with muss less duplicate code.

Comment: @ChrisG - you're a genius!  I adjusted my if statement and took out the 'null' portion and it works well.  Thank you very much

Comment: Thanks, but that's really basic stuff ;)